# Why doesn't Meteor have server-side sessions?

Tags: meteor

I want to create a shopping cart with Meteor that allows non-logged in visitors to have persistent shopping carts.

As far as I can tell, the only way to track a non-logged in visitor in Meteor is to set a persistent ID on the client (localStorage) then pass that ID in every subscribe and method call.

Most web frameworks store a unique session ID in a cookie and that cookie is sent with every request to the server so the server always has a way to identify the visitor who sent the request - why not have similar functionality in Meteor?

It looks like Meteor persists the userId (if logged in) in localStorage and sends that userId to the server over the DDP connection - but that only helps when users are logged in. Why isn't this done with all visitors via a sessionId?

Am I missing something here? Other techniques are welcome - I just want to clean up my code and not have to pass the sessionId around everywhere.

Comment: You right meteor dont support cookies you can read more http://info.meteor.com/blog/session-cookies in here, you can use `local storage` for save any information you need.

Comment: Thanks, that link explains why it hasn't been implemented even with localStorage tokens. Maybe storing carts in localStorage makes the most sense - although I really wanted to have carts tracked server-side so I could easily gather data about abandoned carts.

Comment: Maybe use `new Mongo.ObjectID()` to generate an id, save it inside a session variable and then use a document inside a Mongo collection to save all the data inside. Tread carefully tough, it would probably be best to use a method to manipulate that data. That way you can put in place appropriate security measures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You right meteor dont support cookies you can read more http://info.meteor.com/blog/session-cookies in here, my suggestion use local storage to persist clients without login. Also take a look to how to create UUID in javascript [Create GUID / UUID in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript)

//I commented first and post it here since I think this is the answer my two cents.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the cart is a field in your user collection schema.

Instead, make `Cart` its own collection and have `userID` be the foreign key.

Then, if the user isn't logged in, you can use the localStorage token as the ID: `localStorage.getItem('Meteor.loginToken')`.

Finally, when the user signs up, in your `createUser` callback, you search for a cart with that token. If it exists, update it to the new userId.

This is also a little faster for analytics since you don't have to traverse the entire user collection to get the cart object.